# Bind a view to collections in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

I'm semi-new to backbone. I'm trying to bind a collection to a view so that when a new model is added to a collection, the view is updated. I think when you do this with models you can bind to the model's change event. But how do you do the same with collections?

```
App.Views.Hotels = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'ul',

    render: function() {
        this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
        var floorplanView = new App.Views.Floorplans({collection:floorplanCollection});
        $('.floorplans').html(floorplanView.render().el);
        return this;
    },

    events: {'click': 'addfloorplan'},

    addOne: function(hotel) {
        var hotelView = new App.Views.Hotel ({model:hotel});
        this.$el.append(hotelView.render().el);
    },

    addfloorplan: function() {
        floorplanCollection.add({"name": "another floorplan"});
    }
});

App.Collections.Floorplans = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Floorplan,
    initialize: function () {
        this.bind( "add", function() {console.log("added");} );
    }
});
```

The click event fires and adds to the collection. But how do I get it to update the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to the collection's `add` event, which **fires when a new item is added to the collection**. In modern versions of Backbone, the method `listenTo` is preferred to `bind` or `on` for listening to events. ([Read de documentation for more info](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo))

For example, in your case this should do the trick:

```
App.Views.Hotels = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection,'add', this.addOne);
  },
  //rest of code
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice tutorial I had followed long ago.

[An Intro to Backbone.js: Part 3 – Binding a Collection to a View](http://liquidmedia.org/blog/2011/02/backbone-js-part-3/)

It helps you define a DonutCollectionView that will, when given a collection of donuts, render an UpdatingDonutView for each donut.