# How to make shuffle collection in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Firstly, I sync the collection with server, then I need to render. After this, user can press the button to shuffle data in page( e.g. list of songs ), and script must rerender all items.
I wrote this:

```
  AppCollection.on("add"  , onUpdateItem );

  $( document ).bind("keyup", function(e){
   if( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
     var shuffledCopy = AppCollection.clone().shuffle();
     $("body").html("");
     AppCollection.reset().add( shuffledCopy );
  }
});
```

Maybe you know best pratice for this goal?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299592/bind-a-view-to-collections-in-backbone-js

Comment: does your view listen for Backbone's `add` event?

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of [custom comparators](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator), one with shuffling functionality and the other with default sorts. That way you could swap out comparators per need and just call [AppCollection.sort](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sort).